# Chaining overloaded constructors in C#

Tags: c#

I'm quite new in C# and I'm not sure if I can refactor this class to make these constructors chaining.

I've tried from examples on The Internet, but all of them explain how to chain constructors with a number of parameters in ascending order. I've got constructors here that got two parameters each because the constructor is overloaded. Hope my explanation makes sense.

I'm really struggling with this and any help will be really appreciated.

```
public class MyException: TheException
    {
        public MyException()
        : base()
        {
        }

        public MyException(string message)
        : base(message)
        {           
        }

        public MyException(string message, Exception inner)
        : base(message, inner)
        {
        }

        public MyException(string message, string outcome, Exception inner)
            : base(message, outcome, inner)
        { 
        }

        public MyException(string message, string outcome)
            : base(message, outcome)
        {
        }
}
```

Comment: This is custom exception pattern. This has nothing to do with constructor chaining.

Comment: I established a rule many years ago - never use a custom exception. It meant I was using the exception to control my program flow, which is bad. Never had the need to break that rule.

Comment: You should be right about "never use a custom exception". Thank you. I'll have that in mind when working from scratch. Unfortunately, I had no choice because I'm refactoring code that can't change and had no idea how to chain the constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this` instead of `base` to chain your constructors.
You need to provide your default values. Here's an example.

```
public class MyException: TheException
{
    public MyException()
    : this("default message")
    {
    }
    
    // assuming here you want to call other overload with Exception, not with outcome
    public MyException(string message)
    : this(message, (Exception)null)
    {           
    }

    public MyException(string message, Exception inner)
    : this(message, null, inner)
    {
    }

    public MyException(string message, string outcome)
        : this(message, outcome, null)
    {
    }

    public MyException(string message, string outcome, Exception inner)
        : base(message, outcome, inner)
    { 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any advantage in chaining the constructors? I read that one of the advantages is less duplicated code, but I can see that there are just a few differences in the code.

Comment: @Nika Yes. In above example, logic is in base class so benefits are not in surface. In general, if you are chaining constructors, you can have your constructor logic in one place (the one with most parameters in above example)